# Note (save) unmatched entries for dataset_a and dataset_b with python pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe

As you guys can see we lose values from both frames since certain keys do not match up. What I am looking for is note the number of unmatched entries for  left_frame and right_frame. I am not sure how to do this.

**left_frame**

```
   key left_value
0    0          a
1    1          b
2    2          c
3    3          d
4    4          e
```

**right_frame**

```
   key right_value
0    2           f
1    3           g
2    4           h
3    5           i
4    6           j

pd.merge(left_frame, right_frame, on='key', how='inner')
```

** Desired Output: 1**

```
    key  left_value right_value
0   2    c           f
1   3    d           g
2   4    e           h
```

** Desired Output: 2**

```
   key left_value right_value      _merge
0    0          a         NaN   left_only
1    1          b         NaN   left_only
5    5        NaN           i  right_only
6    6        NaN           j  right_only
```

so basically, I want to have two DataFrames, one for "inner" and other for non-matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the type of merge to 'outer' and pass `indicator=True` then you can see where the non-matching rows come from:

```
In [193]:
pd.merge(left, right, how='outer', indicator=True)

Out[193]:
   key left_value right_value      _merge
0    0          a         NaN   left_only
1    1          b         NaN   left_only
2    2          c           f        both
3    3          d           g        both
4    4          e           h        both
5    5        NaN           i  right_only
6    6        NaN           j  right_only
```

You can `groupby` on this column and call `count`:

```
In [194]:
pd.merge(left, right, how='outer', indicator=True).groupby('_merge').count()

Out[194]:
            key  left_value  right_value
_merge                                  
left_only     2           2            0
right_only    2           0            2
both          3           3            3
```

If you want to filter and save the results:

```
In [198]:
merged = pd.merge(left, right, how='outer', indicator=True)
merged

Out[198]:
   key left_value right_value      _merge
0    0          a         NaN   left_only
1    1          b         NaN   left_only
2    2          c           f        both
3    3          d           g        both
4    4          e           h        both
5    5        NaN           i  right_only
6    6        NaN           j  right_only

In [199]:    
both = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'both']
both

Out[199]:
   key left_value right_value _merge
2    2          c           f   both
3    3          d           g   both
4    4          e           h   both

In [200]:
other = merged[merged['_merge'] != 'both']
other

Out[200]:
   key left_value right_value      _merge
0    0          a         NaN   left_only
1    1          b         NaN   left_only
5    5        NaN           i  right_only
6    6        NaN           j  right_only
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to store them , after I use drop method for non-matching.

Comment: You can filter my output : `both = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'both']` and `others = merged[merged['_merge'] != 'both']`

Comment: thats sounds like it will work. I will try that. Thank you!